# Wanted to create dynamic string in C , but instead of that program makes infinite loop of input char

Tags: c

```
char *increaseSize(char *myString,int size) {

    char *newString = (char*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));//new char[size + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(myString[i] != '\0')
        newString[i] = myString[i];
    }
    newString[size - 1] = getch();
    printf("%c",newString[size - 1]);
    newString[size] = '\0';
    free(myString);

    return newString;
}

int main()
{

    int size = 1;
    char *myString = (char*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    myString[0] = '\0';
    do{
        myString = increaseSize(myString, size);
        size++;

    } while (myString[size - 1] != 13 || myString[size - 1] != '\n');
    printf("\n");
    free(myString);
    return 0;
}
```

Would like to know why after input "Enter" my loop does not stop.

Comment: C or C++? Different languages, different approaches to problems. Also, have you looked at the question preview? Please [edit] to make sure your code's formatted correctly.

Comment: Since this question uses C conventions for the most part, and in the title says C, I would assume that the C++ tag should be removed.

Comment: Your loop isn't stopping because `myString[size - 1] != 13 || myString[size - 1] != '\n'` is *always* true. Any value is *either* not 13 or not `'\n'`. Use `&&` here instead of `||`. You can think of it as `! (myString[size - 1] == 13 || myString[size - 1] == '\n')`

Comment: Your condition is always true. Just change the operator OR `||` to AND `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem in your code is this statement:

```
size++;
```

After returning from `increaseSize()` you are increasing modifying `size` value (doing `size++`) and then checking for `myString[size - 1]` value.

Move `size++` above `increaseSize()` call:

```
size++;
myString = increaseSize(myString, size);
```

Second problem is `||` used in `while` condition:

```
while (myString[size - 1] != 13 || myString[size - 1] != '\n');
```

Replace `||` with `&&`:

```
while ((myString[size - 1] != 13) && (myString[size - 1] != '\n'));
```

After making above changes, you will face one more problem with your code.
When you enter a character and press `Enter` key, the `\n` character will be in input buffer and in next call to `increaseSize()` function the `getch()` will read that stray `\n` character and program will exit. You need to clean up the input buffer after reading character from user.

Comment: Thought that i should put size++ after function . Thx .

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
} while (myString[size - 1] != 13 || myString[size - 1] != '\n');
```

The condition is "while A is true or B is true" where **either** A or B is always going to be true since they complement each other! Because that condition is "I have an X, if X is not equal to two things simultaneously..."

Solution:

```
} while (myString[size - 1] != 13 && myString[size - 1] != '\n');
```

Comment: still don't work

Comment: I didn't debug your code, TBH - this is something you must do yourself. Just pointed out an "obvious" mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is always true:

```
} while (myString[size - 1] != 13 || myString[size - 1] != '\n');
```

Suppose `myString[size - 1]` is equal to `'\n'`.  The second condition is false but the first is true.  And because the logical OR operator `||` evaluates to true if *either* of the operands evaluate to true, then the result is true.  The same applies if `myString[size - 1]` is 13 (better: `'\r'`).

What you want is the logical AND operator `&&`, which requires both operands to be true to evaluate to true:

```
} while (myString[size - 1] != '\r' && myString[size - 1] != '\n');
```